# Moving whole entity graph in DevForce

Tags: c#, entity-framework, devforce

I have following scenario. 2 different Entity managers and needed graph loaded in one Entity manager. I'm working with another instance of entity manager and need those entities moved. I know about detach/attach and I know I can attach whole graph:

http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/entity-add-attach-remove#HAttachingentitygraphs

However, there is no way (at least I can't see it) to detach whole graph. It detaches only head object and leaves childs "orphaned"

> Note that any dependent children of this entity will NOT be removed,
>   they will be "orphaned", meaning that they will no longer have a
>   parent but will still exist in the EntityManager.

Is there any way to move whole graph to my 2nd entity manager?

Answer (score 0):

DevForce doesn't provide an automatic way to detach a whole graph, nor a way to move (as opposed to copy) entities between EntityManagers, but you can still do this in your code.

Use the EntityManager.RemoveEntities(IEnumerable) override to remove multiple entities at one time.  You can build up the list any way you like, and remember the EM also has several FindEntities() methods which can help.

In addition to attach/remove you can also look at using ImportEntities or the various EntityCacheState methods.  These don't do a "move" either, but could be easier to work with in some situations.  There's more info here - http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/start-entity-cache.